# How to use loops to print the below pattern?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to produce this pattern:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Currently, I represent a row with `range(1,6)` and I get five rows with the outer loop.  I use an inner loop that represents `j` with `range(1,i)` five columns.

But I am not getting the desired outcome as above.

This is what i have started with:

```py
for i in range(1,6):#where i represents 5 Rows
    print('list of int inside range:',i)
    for j in range(1,i):#where j represents 5 columns
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- You need to avoid printing a newline on each print, and instead print it at the end of each outer loop.  Use the `end` parameter to `print` to do this.
- Your use of `range()` isn't quite right -- for example, in the first loop you'd be doing `range(1,1)` which has no values.  This is called an 'off by one' error.  Instead, start it at 0 and print one higher than the value of `j`.

With the above changes, and removing the debug `print` that you were doing:

```py
for i in range(1,6):#where i represents 5 Rows
    for j in range(0,i):#where j represents 5 columns
        print(j+1, end='')
    print();
```